# Split a timer job based on content database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

**Background:** Currently in our SP Farm there is one custom timer job 'X' we developed and scheduled at the web application level (using `SPAllSitesJobDefinition` as base class and override the `ProcessSite` method). The Timer job ran for each content DB.

We have very large number of site collection exist for this web application. We want to split the timer job because it take too much RAM and time. Is this any way I can split the timer job based on the content database/ managed path?

Answer (score 1):

there is one option which you can use and this is for per content database. If you have multiple content database in the web application then you can set on which server all the timers jobs for the content database.

- from central admin go to Application management > Manage Content Database
- On this page click on 1st content database and on database settings page
- in the bottom of page you will see the option "Preferred Server for Timer Jobs" and select the server where u want to run the timer jobs
- repeat this for each content database and select the appropriate server.
  [image]

Also read this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/sharepoint-2010-internals-timer-jobs2/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Is there any way to split the timer job based some logic so the timer job will run for the specific content database and will not trigger for every content database.